# double to hex. How It's Made?

Tags: double, decimal, hex

**157,453796** = hex **18068A**

157,455093 = hex 180697

**71,5037**    = hex **E91D00**

71,506104  = hex E93500

71,507103  = hex E93F00

**0**          = hex **000000**

I know exactly what it is not IEEE 754

Comment: Questions like this are better addressed on a site like http://mathoverflow.net/.  The site is specific to programing and while hex is used in computers a lot, it's not programming per se.

Comment: I would say that this is still considerable pertinent to SO..

Comment: Ask question more exlicitly. telepathists are on vacations currently

Answer (score 0):

The following depends on the byte-order of your processor architecture and thus can't be read back on every system:

```
double f = 10020.2093;
char acz[sizeof(double)+1] = '\0';
std::copy((char*)(&f), ((char*)&f)+sizeof(double), acz);
```